# Install Gravis gamepad pro (gameport) in Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, game-controller

I have a Gravis gamepad pro with a Creative gameport connection and try to install this gamepad in Windows Vista but have failed so far. After some work the gameport on the sound card has been successfully installed and recognized. Installing the Gravis software also went successful, but the gamepads are not detected automatically. I had the same issue with an old computer with Windows XP, however there I could manually add the gamepads by going to Control Panel -> Game Controllers and then press the Add button to add the gamepad manually. In Windows Vista there is however no such Add button. When I go to Control Panel -> Game Controllers there is only an Advanced button, which list the game devices currently installed, which is none. The odd thing is, I read several web pages where they tell me to add the gamepad manually in Windows Vista by clicking on the Add button in Control Panel -> Game Controllers, but there is no such button. I also tried using Control Panel -> Add Hardware and try to add it manually there, but the inf-files in the installed Gravis directory do not allow me to install a gamepad. Any help is appreciated. I would also be content if it would work as some generic 4-button gamepad.